# Using USER_TAB_COLLS in SQL to retrieve values from columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to get the names of all the tables that contain a specific column name. Now for all these tables with that column name, I want to retrieve the tables with a specific value in that column.

The Query being Used for Getting the list of tables is:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM USER_TAB_COLS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'USER_ID';
```

Pls help me to complete this query. I am new to SQL.
Example:

```
WEB_APPLICATION (TABLE-1)
USER_ID NAME GENDER
abc     ABC  M

DESKTOP_APPLICATION (TABLE-2)
LOGIN_ID NAME GENDER
bcd      BCD  F

MOBILE_APPLICATION(TABLE-3)
USER_ID NAME GANDER
abc     ABC  F

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
TABLE_NAME          GENDER
WEB_APPLICATION     M
MOBILE_APPLICATION  F
```

Now I want to get the tables with the column USER_ID and the value as abc.

Hope I made myself clear this time around.

Comment: What if there are thousands of rows in the column in a particular table? what should your output look like?

Comment: How shall I complete this then? Is there any way to access the values of the columns given that I am doing a select on USER_TAB_COLS?

Comment: there is. but what will your output look like? how do you expect it?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the expected output. Sorry for the inconvenience .

Comment: Think requires PLSQL

Answer (score 1):

You'll need dynamic SQL for this, so you can do this in PL/SQL.

```
declare
cursor TABS is
  SELECT TABLE_NAME 
  FROM USER_TAB_COLS 
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
  HAVING COUNT(
    CASE 
      WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('USER_ID','GENDER') 
    THEN 1 END
  ) = 2;
  type tab is table of varchar(100) index by pls_integer;
  v_tab tab;
begin
  for t in TABS loop
    execute immediate 'select gender from ' ||t.table_name bulk collect into v_tab;
    if v_tab.count > 0 then 
      for i in v_tab.first..v_tab.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(t.table_name ||'    '|| v_tab(i));
      end loop;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

This query creates the required SQL statement (one row for each table)

```
select 
'select '''||table_name||''' table_name, gender from '|| table_name ||
' where USER_ID = ''abc''' || 
case when rn != 1 then ' UNION ALL ' end as sql_txt
from (
select table_name,
row_number() over (order by table_name desc) as rn
from (
select table_name from user_tab_columns where column_name = 'GENDER'
INTERSECT
select table_name from user_tab_columns where column_name = 'USER_ID'
))  order by table_name;
```

Running it you get statement such as

```
select 'MOBILE_APPLICATION' table_name, gender from MOBILE_APPLICATION where USER_ID = 'abc' UNION ALL 
select 'WEB_APPLICATION' table_name, gender from WEB_APPLICATION where USER_ID = 'abc';
```

If you run it you get the required result

```
TABLE_NAME         GENDER
------------------ ------
MOBILE_APPLICATION F      
WEB_APPLICATION    M
```

*sample data*

```
create table WEB_APPLICATION as
select 'abc' USER_ID, 'ABC' NAME, 'M' GENDER from dual;

create table DESKTOP_APPLICATION as
select 'bcd' LOGIN_ID, 'BCD' NAME, 'F' GENDER from dual;

create table MOBILE_APPLICATION as
select 'abc' USER_ID, 'ABC' NAME, 'F' GENDER from dual;
```